# Webdriver-manage update error

Tags: node.js, selenium, protractor, webdriver-manager

I am new to using protractor. Trying to install a standalone `webdriver-manager` but getting following error.

```
Node v7.2.0
Protractor 5.0.0
webdriver-manager 11.1.1
```

when I run `webdriver-manger update --standalone` I get following error

```
[17:25:21] I/file_manager - creating folder C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium
[17:25:22] E/downloader - undefined
[17:25:22] I/update - chromedriver: file exists C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_2.26win32.zip
[17:25:22] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.26win32.zip
**(node:14972) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Invalid filename
(node:14972) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[17:25:22] E/downloader - undefined
[17:25:22] I/update - selenium standalone: file exists** C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar
[17:25:22] I/update - selenium standalone: 2.53.1 up to date
[17:25:24] E/downloader - undefined
[17:25:24] I/update - geckodriver: file exists C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\geckodriver-v0.12.0-win64.zip
[17:25:24] I/update - geckodriver: unzipping geckodriver-v0.12.0-win64.zip
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce it using protractor 5.0.0 on mac. Have you tried removing the `node_modules`, cleaning cache with `npm cache clean` and reinstalling everything from scratch?

Comment: Could be Node 7. I have not tested this on node 7. I will investigate this tomorrow.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with node version 7.4.0 and webdriver-manager on master on my mac. I'll also check Windows since it appears you are also running Windows... tomorrow.

Comment: removing node_module and clean cache did not help. I am behind a proxy server do I need to add my proxy details for webdridver-manager update

Comment: Forgot to mention I am using windows

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
webdriver-manager --ignore_ssl update
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The missing proxy configuration caused this non sense output.

The following command worked:

```
webdriver-manager update --proxy "http://<user>:<pw>@webproxy.<company>.com:8080/"
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem in protected network:

webdriver-manager update --proxy http://127.0.0.1:8888/

worked for me and I was successfully able to update the web-drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problem with the java installation. I installed the latest java update, opened a new shell and the issue was resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Adding --ignore_ssl should solve the problem.
2. Those working with local webdrivers instead of global, need to run
   this in your project base directory -

   ```
   node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager --ignore_ssl update
   ```
3. Those working with Protractor together with [gulp-protractor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-protractor)
   plugin - You'll have to update the webdriver-manager at two
   locations in your local node_modules directory:

   node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager
   node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager

   The second location is where gulp-protractor looks for the
   webdrivers. So two commands that you need to run are:

   ```
   node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager --ignore_ssl update
   node
   node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager
   --ignore_ssl update
   ```